# Understanding struct task list_head

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have a struct `my_struct` I found a guide saying there is a linked list that is really easy to use, all I need to do is include a `task list_head` in my struct, but I don't understand how to traverse this list correctly because **I don't know how the list is actually structured**

[edit] How does this kernel link list actually work? Please explain.

```
#include <linux/blkdev.h>
#include <linux/bio.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
```

try this outside of kernel:

```
 #include "list.h"

// my list of elements
struct my_struct
{
    struct task list_head;
}
```

I then declare the head of my list:

```
struct my_struct *head;
```

Memory is malloc for the head like this:

```
head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
```

I could use something like;

```
int count_elements_in_list()
{
   int size = 0;

   struct my_list *pos;

   list_for_each(pos, head)
   {
      size++;
   }

   return size;
}
```

Can someone explain how this linked list actually works?

Comment: You can't traverse this as is, there is nothing to traverse, so is your question how to traverse a non existing list or how to build a linked list?

Comment: I am pretty sure the list exists. I malloc for the head at the start.

Comment: We can't answer without seeing the struct which defines the list elements.

Comment: @keshlam It is the `my_struct`. That was fairly clear, I am surprised that you and the person that upvoted you didn't see it. I will make it more obvious on the post!

Comment: The compiler needs a definition for `struct task` to be able to compile `struct my_struct`.  If you had `struct task *list_head` inside `struct my_struct`, then the details of `struct task` would not be needed until you needed to access data inside the task structure.

Comment: @user3555302, I assume that there is an #included '.h' file which describes 'for_each()'.  I believe that the '.h' file is the key to understanding the code.

Comment: Actually, no; it is fairly unclear — not clear at all (since I'm the one who up-voted the comment).  To create a linked list, you need some pointers; you have no pointers on display.  This is why we're puzzled.  You have not given us the information which is critical to answering your question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when you say "pointers" you mean `next` and `previous` right? Well it seems that for this kind of kernel list you don't need that, that is why it looks so weird to me.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer I didn't include a .h for either `struct task list_head` or `list_for_each()` and it compiles.

Comment: Are you working in the kernel?  Which header defines `struct task`?  Whatever the magic, it hinges on what is defined in the header, and since we have no idea which header(s) you're including, it is not possible to answer the question — yet.  Please provide the missing information.  You say you didn't include the header; that is incorrect — but you may not have included it directly.  You'll have to point out where you read about this list, perhaps, so we can read what you're not telling us.  The code won't compile without a header that (a) defines `struct task` and (b) defines `for_each`.

Comment: @user3555302; interesting.  What compiler are you using?  gcc?

Comment: Great — now someone with access to the source code can help you.  Me; I'm not going to hunt those headers down if they aren't on my Linux VM (and, sadly, they aren't among the headers on my VM).

Comment: yes gcc in Ubuntu VM. I am trying to narrow down the header file to one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Outside the kernel you can find it in `#include "list.h"` So to simplify my question (edited above) how does one go about using this kernel link list and how does it work?

Comment: The guide you found, you sure they are using `struct task list_head;` not `struct list_head task;` ?

Comment: Only if it is present; there is no `/usr/include/list.h` on my Ubuntu VM.  I'm not set up to build kernels; I don't have any plans to change that.

Comment: A bit obscure IMO [list.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h)

Comment: For sure you can include list.h without doing any kernel. I just found it on my other VM which is not ready for kernel modules. Thank you @CasperVonB

Comment: Some suggested reading: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-11-sect-5, http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LinkedLists, http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you included "module.h"; which is a standard include module for most all Linux kernel modules.  The "module.h" file includes "list.h".

(These include headers can be found under /usr/src/linux/)

-

The 'list.h' kernel header file defines the -only- acceptable linked list implementation for the Linux kernel (as per kernel.org folks).  In tern, 'list.h' includes 'types.h', which define the following:

```
struct list_head { 
   struct list_head *next, *prev;
   }
```

In the code supplied to your question:

```
 struct task list_head;
```

'struct task' contains a 'struct list_head' element.  Then later:

```
list_for_each()
```

which is defined in 'list.h', which requires uses 'pos' and 'head' to iterate the list.